# Open a Cordova app with chrome or other webkit browser?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

We are building a Meteor app that uses Cordova to build a mobile app implementation of our web app. I was curious if it's possible to build the app and then open it in a browser for easier debugging. I've been using the safari dev tools to debug the ios application in both the simulator and on an actual device, but being able to adjust the screen width/height and having access to say, Chrome's dev tools would be hugely beneficial to my testing process. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For some simple things, like CSS and some plugins, you can use the browser platform. Just add:

cordova platform add browser